# Вывод данных в скрипт из div'a

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт тизерной сети, в параметре нужно динамически подтянуть информацию из сайта. Грубо говоря, чтобы параметр был равен строке на сайте (ID товара).

Кусок кода для понимания: :

```
w.MgSensorData = { cid: 247262, lng: "ru", nosafari: true, eid: , partner: 105773 };
```

Как видите, `eid` без параметра. Нужно чтобы `eid` был равен ID товара на сайте.

Скриншот: http://joxi.ru/vn2YVxGh9LKZA6

То есть, по примеру, если код будет показан на странице товара с ID 923470895, он будет иметь вид:

```
w.MgSensorData = { cid: 247262, lng: "ru", nosafari: true, eid: 923470895, partner: 105773 };
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="table-container">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%">Номер товара</td>
                <td>955094881</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: <h2 class="table-container">
  <table class="table table-condensed">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:40%">Номер товара</td>
      <td>955094881</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для HTML-кода из вопроса:

- Выбирается первый элемент с классом `table-container`.
- Внутри него ищутся элементы с тегом `td`, и берётся второй из них.
- Берётся текстовое значение найденного элемента.

```js
var w = { };
w.MgSensorData = { cid: 247262, lng: "ru", nosafari: true, eid: 0, partner: 105773 }; 

w.MgSensorData.eid = document.getElementsByClassName('table-container')[0]
        .getElementsByTagName('td')[1].textContent;
console.log(w.MgSensorData);
```

```html
<h2 class="table-container">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%">Номер товара</td>
                <td>955094881</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h2>
```

И аналогичный код с использованием jQuery:

```js
var w = { };
w.MgSensorData = { cid: 247262, lng: "ru", nosafari: true, eid: 0, partner: 105773 }; 

w.MgSensorData.eid = $('.table-container:first td').eq(1).text();
console.log(w.MgSensorData);
```

```html
<h2 class="table-container">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%">Номер товара</td>
                <td>955094881</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h2>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```